# CSS For Changing the main navigation background color

Tags: css, wordpress, navigation

I'm trying to set the color of the background of the main header for the site cheswickwarriorsfutbol.com to #3f406d. I've used the following codes and they don't seem to be working.

```
.main-navigation {
color: #3f406d;
}

.hm-nav-container {
background-color: #3f406d;
}

.navigation-top {
background-color: #3f406d;
}
```

Can anybody help? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`.mh-custom-header` is the css selector you're looking for.

```
/* custom header */
.mh-custom-header {
  background-color: #3f406d!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close.

Try this class instad:

```
.mh-header {
    background-color: #e26060;
}
```

Along with that class, you may also want to affect the .mh-custom-header class with the same property

Answer (score 0):

@Calvin Langer, your line of coding worked perfectly. Thank you! That was quick!